# using range in rails to map array values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code

Consider this is as range as a input

```
ranges = ["1000-2000", "2001-5000", "5001-25000", "25001-0"]

def price_ranges ranges
    ranges.collect{|x| x.split('-')}.map { 
      |ar| 
        Range.new(Integer(ar.first), Integer(ar.second))  
          if Range.new(Integer(ar.first), Integer(ar.second)).eql?(25001..0)
            Range.new(Integer(ar.first), Float::INFINITY)
          end
    }
  end
```

Actual output I need is

```
[1000..2000, 2001..5000, 5001..25000, 25001..Infinity]
```

But am getting like

```
[nil, nil, nil, 25001..Infinity]
```

How to modify the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ranges = ["1000-2000", "2001-5000", "5001-25000", "25001-0"]

    def price_ranges ranges
        ranges.collect{|x| x.split('-')}.map { 
          |ar|
              range = Range.new(Integer(ar.first), Integer(ar.second)) 
              if range.eql?(25001..0)
                Range.new(Integer(ar.first), Float::INFINITY)
              else
                range
              end
        }
      end
```

For the first 3 elements of your array, you are getting the `nil` from the `if` evaluation

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gsub` within a `map` of your `ranges` array:

```
1.9.3p448 :008 > ranges = ["1000-2000", "2001-5000", "5001-25000", "25001-0"]
 => ["1000-2000", "2001-5000", "5001-25000", "25001-0"] 

1.9.3p448 :010 > ranges.map {|range| range.gsub(/-/, "..") }
 => ["1000..2000", "2001..5000", "5001..25000", "25001..0"]
```

Then within your loop, you can `eval` each string:

```
1.9.3p448 :016 > eval(ranges.map {|range| range.gsub(/-/, "..") }.first)
 => 1000..2000 

1.9.3p448 :017 > _.class
 => Range
```

Note that for your last range, if you want `Infinity`, you can use:

```
1.9.3p448 :012 > 1.0/0.0
 => Infinity
```